# Where does Visual Studio get Inherited Values for a project's Include Directories?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've inherited a large project maintained in Visual Studio 2022 Community.

A Solution includes a Project of interest.

Clicking on the project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories->value->down-carat->Edit I get a dialog showing a few settings for that project, but then **Inherited Values** that are of interest.

Where are these set?  I thought they were in solution->Properties in earlier VC++ but I'm not seeing them there.